# Setting up @RequestBody when sending a JSON-body containing object of object and arrays

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, post

My json object that is sent to backend looks like this:

```
{  
   "reportAccess":{  
      "report":{  
         "id":70,
         "reportName":"Test Rapport",
         "created":"2017-06-01",
         "description":"Test report",
         "modifiedDate":"2017-06-01T12:10:00.000+0000",
         "modifiedBy":"111111"
      },
      "accessGroup":{  
         "id":1,
         "accessName":"Administrator"
      },
      "validFromDate":"2017-07-24",
      "validToDate":"2017-07-30"
   },
   "users":[  
      {  
         "id":111111,
         "employeeNumber":"123456",
         "firstName":"Test1",
         "lastName":"Test11",
         "windowsId":"t1234567"
      },
      {  
         "id":222222,
         "employeeNumber":"7891011",
         "firstName":"Test2",
         "lastName":"Test22",
         "windowsId":"t7891011"
      }
   ]
}
```

The frontend post call:

```
function addAccessForMultipleAgents(access, users) {
            var holderWrapper = {
                reportAccess: access,
                users: users
            };
            return utils.post('/api/v1/reportAccesses/all', holderWrapper);
        }
```

Backend, I have a wrapper Object that looks like this:

**HolderWrapper.java**

```
public class HolderWrapper {
    private List<User> users;
    private ReportAccessCustom reportAccess;

    public HolderWrapper() {
    }

    public HolderWrapper(List<User> users, ReportAccessCustom reportAccess) {
        this.users = users;
        this.reportAccess = reportAccess;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public ReportAccessCustom getReportAccess() {
        return reportAccess;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HolderWrapper{" +
                "users=" + users +
                ", reportAccess=" + reportAccess +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**ReportAccessCustom.java**

```
public class ReportAccessCustom {
    private Report report;
    private AccessGroup accessGroup;
    private Date validFromDate;
    private Date validToDate;

    public Report getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public AccessGroup getAccessGroup() {
        return accessGroup;
    }

    public Date getValidFromDate() {
        return validFromDate;
    }

    public Date getValidToDate() {
        return validToDate;
    }
}
```

And the code that handles the POST-request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<ReportAccess> createMultipleAccesses(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> holderWrapper) {
        List<ReportAccess> response = new ArrayList<>();

        HolderWrapper hw = new HolderWrapper((ArrayList<User>) holderWrapper.get("users"), (ReportAccessCustom) holderWrapper.get("reportAccess"));
        List<User> users = hw.getUsers();
        ReportAccessCustom reportAccessCustom = hw.getReportAccess();


      //rest of code..
        return response;
    }
```

All this leaves me with the error-message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.tn.reportaccess.ReportAccessCustom
```

Any help as to why this fail would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you define your parameter as `HolderWrapper  holderWrapper`?

Comment: @Thomas `@RequestBody HolderWrapper holderWrapper` you mean? I tried that end ended up with `NullPointerException`. How should I model the object frontend then?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your payload. It has a double `{` for reportAccess:

```
{
    "reportAccess": {
        {                 <--- REMOVE THIS AND ...
          "report": {
            "id": 70,
            ...
          },
          "accessGroup": {
            "id": 1,
            ...
          },
          "validFromDate": "2017-07-24",
          "validToDate": "2017-07-30"
        }                <--- ... THIS ONE TOO
    },
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 111111,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 222222,
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

BTW, you do not need to use a Map for your request body, you could use HolderWrapper directly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<ReportAccess> createMultipleAccesses(@RequestBody HolderWrapper holderWrapper) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: My actual code doesn't have those extra braces. That was a formatting-error while writing the question. Good catch though. And when I use `HolderWrapper` directly I get a `NullPointerException`. But if I do that, how should I change my object frontend?

Comment: At what point you get NPE? Show the trace, please. What spring version are you using? Show your config as well, please

Comment: If I use `HolderWrapper ` directly, I get a `NullPointerException` when I use the `getters` from `HolderWrapper` instance. But If do use that directly. How sohuld the object I'm sending from the frontend look? Springer version is `1.5.4.RELEASE`

Comment: Your payload looks fine. It should match your beans. Are you sending your javascript object as a json or as form urlenconded?

Comment: I got it working with `HolderWrapper ` directly :) All I had to do was: `JSON.stringify(holderWrapper)` in my frontend post-call.

Comment: @Nilzone- that indicates your payload didn't match your bean at some place :)